# Get 406 Not Acceptable Error for AngularJs modal with asp.net in Visual Studio

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis-express

After trying to run down a 406 error that occurred whenever I tried to display an html page modally using AngularJS and bootstrap (uibModal), I discovered that the error is limited to one computer of the three I use, leading me to believe that the problem must be configuration on the problem machine. I have not been able to figure out where the issue is. Each computer uses Visual Studio 2015 with an exact copy of the project, down to all dependencies, using IISExpress during debug. I created the demo version here and confirmed the same behavior - works on two, fails on one. Hoping someone can at least get me looking in the right direction. I've tried seeing whether there are differences in the settings for IIS Express, but I don't see anything that jumps out.

I start with the basic AspNet MVC project. Here's the _Layouts.cshtml page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/app");
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap");
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false);
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/controllers");
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery");
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Index.cshtml page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="..\Content\bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="..\Content\default.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="..\Content\site.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="modal-dialog" data-backdrop="false" style="z-index: 1100;">
    <!--<div class="modal fade" id="createModal" data-backdrop="false" style="z-index: 1100;">-->
    <h1>Terms and Conditions</h1>
    <p>Last updated: February 25, 2018</p>
    <p>
        Please read these Terms and Conditions ("Terms", "Terms and Conditions") carefully before using the website (the "Service") operated by My Fake Company ("us", "we", or "our").
        Your access to and use of the Service is conditioned upon your acceptance of and compliance with these Terms. These Terms apply to all visitors, users and others who wish to access or use the Service.
        By accessing or using the Service you agree to be bound by these Terms. If you disagree with any part of the terms then you do not have permission to access the Service.
    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the AngularJS module:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap', 'ngMessages']);

var serviceBase = 'http://localhost:46497/';
app.constant('ngAuthSettings', {
    apiServiceBaseUri: serviceBase,
    clientId: 'ngAuthApp'
});

app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptorService');
});
```

Here is the interceptor (it does not appear to be involved in the issue because it doesn't get hit after the modal is called, but full disclosure):

```
'use strict';
app.factory('authInterceptorService', ['$q',  function ($q) {

    var authInterceptorServiceFactory = {};

    var request = function (config) {
        var contentType = config.headers["Content-Type"];
        config.headers = config.headers || {};
    config.headers = {};

        if (config.headers.Accept != null)
            config.headers.Accept = null;
        if (contentType !== '' && typeof contentType !== 'undefined')
            config.headers["Content-Type"] = contentType;
        return config;
    }


    authInterceptorServiceFactory.request = request;

    return authInterceptorServiceFactory;
}]);
```

And here is my AngularJS controller:

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('app');
app.controller('createAccountCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', '$timeout', '$uibModal', function ($scope, $window, $timeout, $uibModal) {
    var vm = $scope;

    vm.viewTerms = function () {
        $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: '/termsAndConditions.html',
            backdrop: false,
            windowClass: 'modal',
            controller: function (
            $uibModalInstance) {
                vm.close = function () {
                    $uibModalInstance.close('cancel');
                };
            }

        });
    }

}]);
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you use Fiddler to learn which HTTP request triggers the 406 response? That would explain a lot itself.

Comment: I used developer tools (and studio with IE) to see that it is the call to open the modal dialog box. I assume it is the open method, since that's the only method.

Comment: Like I said, dig at HTTP level and see what are the request and response messages. You currently focus too much on code level, and that cannot easily tell why 406 is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by building a new project. I copied code into the new project. I suspect that something somewhere was corrupted in the csproj file, or the applicationHost.config (IISExpress) and I wasn't seeing it. The only physical difference I could find was that the bad csproj had a reference to TypeScript 2.2, which I thought I had removed but looks like NuGet was putting back. I'm not using typescript (angularJs 1.X) so that did stand out. The new version works and that was the main issue.